# Circular draggable slider in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I need to prepare a UI with a circular slider where I can pass value or move drag the pointer to slide in the slider similar to the screenshot attached.
[image]

[image]

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check out this quick solution. I have 0 degrees at the right but you can reverse the quadrants to suit your needs.

```
@Composable
fun Content() {
    var radius by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }

    var shapeCenter by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero)
    }

    var handleCenter by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero)
    }

    var angle by remember {
        mutableStateOf(20.0)
    }

    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                    handleCenter += dragAmount

                    angle = getRotationAngle(handleCenter, shapeCenter)
                    change.consume()
                }
            }
            .padding(30.dp)

    ) {
        shapeCenter = center

        radius = size.minDimension / 2

        val x = (shapeCenter.x + cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * radius).toFloat()
        val y = (shapeCenter.y + sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * radius).toFloat()

        handleCenter = Offset(x, y)

        drawCircle(color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.10f), style = Stroke(20f), radius = radius)
        drawArc(
            color = Color.Yellow,
            startAngle = 0f,
            sweepAngle = angle.toFloat(),
            useCenter = false,
            style = Stroke(20f)
        )

        drawCircle(color = Color.Cyan, center = handleCenter, radius = 60f)
    }
}

private fun getRotationAngle(currentPosition: Offset, center: Offset): Double {
    val (dx, dy) = currentPosition - center
    val theta = atan2(dy, dx).toDouble()

    var angle = Math.toDegrees(theta)

    if (angle < 0) {
        angle += 360.0
    }
    return angle
}
```

[image: screencap]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solution in this [code](https://github.com/philipplackner/ComposeTimer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/plcoding/composetimer/MainActivity.kt) on Github.
Just replace the angle value in Canvas.

Comment: The problem is I need a draggable as well, to drag and manage values

Answer (score 0):

[Circular scrollable Progress bar / Circular slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCNgJ.jpg)

Code :

```
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.StrokeCap
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.Stroke
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInteropFilter
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.onGloballyPositioned
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import kotlin.math.PI
import kotlin.math.abs
import kotlin.math.atan2
import kotlin.math.min

val ColorPrimary = Color(0xFF1c2026)
val LightGreen = Color(0xFF8dc387)
val ProgressBarBg = Color(0xFFFFE9DD)
val ProgressBarProgress = Color(0xFFE08868)
val ProgressBarTint = Color(0xFFE1BAAA)


@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun MuneerCircularProgressBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    padding: Float = 50f,
    stroke: Float = 35f,
    cap: StrokeCap = StrokeCap.Round,
    initialAngle : Double = 0.0,
    onProgressChanged: (progress: Double) -> Unit,
) {
    var width by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var height by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var radius by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var center by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }

    var appliedAngle by remember {
        mutableStateOf(initialAngle)
    }
    var lastAngle by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0.0)
    }

    Canvas(modifier = modifier
        .size(270.dp)
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            width = it.size.width
            height = it.size.height
            center = Offset(width / 2f, height / 2f)
            radius = min(width.toFloat(), height.toFloat()) / 2f - padding - stroke / 2f
        }
        .pointerInteropFilter {

            when (it.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {

                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    appliedAngle = if (center.x > it.x && center.y > it.y) {
                        270 + deltaAngle(center.x - it.x, center.y - it.y)
                    } else {
                        90 - deltaAngle(it.x - center.x, center.y - it.y)
                    }

                    val diff = abs(lastAngle - appliedAngle)
                    if (diff > 180) {
                        appliedAngle = if (appliedAngle < 180) {
                            360.0
                        } else {
                            0.0
                        }
                    }

                    onProgressChanged(appliedAngle / 360.0)
                    lastAngle = appliedAngle

                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {

                }
                else -> return@pointerInteropFilter false
            }

            return@pointerInteropFilter true
        }
    ) {
        drawArc(
            color = ProgressBarBg,
            startAngle = -90f,
            sweepAngle = 360f,
            useCenter = false,
            topLeft = center - Offset(radius, radius),
            size = Size(radius * 2, radius * 2),
            style = Stroke(
                width = stroke,
                cap = cap
            )
        )


        drawArc(
            color = ProgressBarProgress,
            startAngle = -90f,
            sweepAngle = abs(appliedAngle.toFloat()),
            topLeft = center - Offset(radius, radius),
            size = Size(radius * 2, radius * 2),
            useCenter = false,
            style = Stroke(
                width = stroke,
                cap = cap
            )
        )
        drawCircle(
            color = ProgressBarTint,
            radius = stroke,
            center = center + Offset(
                radius * kotlin.math.cos((-90 + abs(appliedAngle)) * PI / 180f).toFloat(),
                radius * kotlin.math.sin((-90 + abs(appliedAngle)) * PI / 180f).toFloat()
            )
        )

        drawCircle(
            color = ColorPrimary,
            radius = ((stroke*2.0)/3.0).toFloat(),
            center = center + Offset(
                radius * kotlin.math.cos((-90 + abs(appliedAngle)) * PI / 180f).toFloat(),
                radius * kotlin.math.sin((-90 + abs(appliedAngle)) * PI / 180f).toFloat()
            )
        )

        drawLine(
            color = LightGreen,
            start = center + Offset(
                (radius-10) * kotlin.math.cos((-90 + abs(appliedAngle)) * PI / 180f).toFloat(),
                (radius-10) * kotlin.math.sin((-90 + abs(appliedAngle)) * PI / 180f).toFloat()
            ),
            end = center + Offset(
                (radius+10) * kotlin.math.cos((-90 + abs(appliedAngle)) * PI / 180f).toFloat(),
                (radius+10) * kotlin.math.sin((-90 + abs(appliedAngle)) * PI / 180f).toFloat()
            )

        )

    }

}

fun deltaAngle(x: Float, y: Float): Double {
    return Math.toDegrees(atan2(y.toDouble(), x.toDouble()))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**